# SQLite-NET installation guide

Tags: xamarin, sqlite-net

I'm new to Xamarin, MonoTouch and C#, but I have got the hang of it. I found `SQLite-NET` in here https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net but I'm not sure how to "install" it, I mean, should I just use the `SQLite.cs` file, or maybe reference the whole project, etc...

What are the steps to use SQLite-NET on a Xamarin project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the version from the [component store](http://components.xamarin.com/view/sqlite-net).  From inside your solution you should be able to click on components and search for SQLite, then click Install.  It will download and install the DLLs for you, add the reference, and provide you with getting started documentation.